# unable to update extension from composer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, server-setup, composer-update

I am trying to update one of my payment gateway extension through composer and the command is

composer update razorpay/update

But I am getting the below errors

Problem 1
- guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.2.0 requires php ^7.2.5 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.1.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.1.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.0.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Conclusion: don't install facebook/php-business-sdk 9.0.3
- Conclusion: don't install facebook/php-business-sdk 9.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install facebook/php-business-sdk 9.0.1
- Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.4.1
- Installation request for facebook/php-business-sdk ^9.0 -> satisfiable by facebook/php-business-sdk[9.0.0, 9.0.1, 9.0.2, 9.0.3].
- Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.4.1
- facebook/php-business-sdk 9.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5 || ^7.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.2.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.0, 6.4.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.1, 6.4.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.2, 6.4.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.3, 6.4.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.4, 6.4.1].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.5, 6.4.1].
- Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.4.1) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.4.1]

Previously I am trying to install the Facebook Pixel extension due to some technical issues we didn't install.
After that when I am trying to install or update the extension I am getting the above error.

For reference please find the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem with my Magento 2.3.1 with PHP version 7.2.17

```
- facebook/php-business-sdk 11.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5 || ^7.0
```

Tried lower version of SDK as per your Facebook_Business extension version or require.

I tried with lower SDK version 8.0.0 and its working fine in my case.

```
composer require facebook/php-business-sdk 8.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are installing guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.2.0 version which requires php version ^7.2.5 || ^8.0 and your PHP version is (7.1.33).

So, upgrade your php version to 7.3 or 7.2.5.